# jquery mousewheel vertical scrolling website

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, mousewheel

Heloo,

How can I accomplish this kind of vertical mousewheel scrolling?

http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA8

It always "knows" which div is active and based on mousewheel direction it scrolls to certain div, up or down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The demo is not opening for me, but similar question was asked at GreenSock forums.
Here is a script that does something similar to what you asked:
http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/dLxAJ